# Java Command Line Arguements

Tags: java, oop, command-line-arguments

This is my code for the java command line argument that I am trying to make it work however it doesn't allow me to do so.

I have to write a class containing the main method and another class methods (so there are two class methods in this class).

The main method calls the other class method and passes to it as arguments three command line arguments converted to double.

The class method then returns the middle number of the three in a specific output format.

The user will input three numbers which will then be outputted in to the numbers class below.

This is my first class and it is called Numbers:

```
    // import java.util.Scanner;
    // import java.util.Arrays;
    // import java.util.List;
    // import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Numbers {

        public Numbers() {
        }

        public static void main (String[] args) {
            Middle.main(args);
        }
    }
```

This is my second class called Middle and this is supposed to be linked with the Numbers class from above and it should send the array double arguments which the user types in and then it gets stored and then outputted back to the Numbers class.

```
public class Middle{

public void Middle()
{
}

public static void main(String[]args)
{
    double num, i, j, temp;

    double a,b,c;
    a = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    b = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
    c = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);

    //USE COLLECTIONS.SORT OR BUBBLESORT

    num = input.nextDouble();

    int array[] = new int[num];

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) 
    array[i] = input.nextInt();

for (i = 0; i < ( num - 1 ); i++) 
{
  for (j = 0; j < num - i - 1; j++) 
  {
    if (array[j] > array[j+1]) 
    {
       temp = array[j];
       array[j] = array[j+1];
       array[j+1] = temp;
    }
  }
}
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) 
    System.out.println(array[i]);


    if(args.length ==3)
    {
    System.out.println(b + " is between " + a + " and " + c);
    }
    else
    {
    System.out.println("Error");    
    }
}
```

}

I am using BlueJ to test my program, and that the command line arguments are typed inside the bracket and inside with double quotes, i.e. {"5","6.3","3"}.

I have used bubblesort however the error that keeps on propping up is cannot find symbol method nextDouble().

Is the format right the way I have used bubblesort if not any advice would be helpful.

Comment: There's actually no real logic here.  If your `if` condition were fixed to be `args.length == 3`, then it would print out whatever your middle number was, and claim that it was between your first and last number.  That said, what kind of output are you giving this program and what output are you getting back?

Comment: That is not how you pass arguments to java. `java -cp . Numbers 5 6.3 3`

Comment: *My code doesn't seem to be working*. That's a much too vague description. Tell precisely what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: What does it mean "my code doesn't seem to be working"? What does your code do?

Comment: It just produces an error by stating -> expected

Answer (score 0):

the String array args given in the main method automatically delimits the input by spaces so to have an String[] args.length = 3 you would need to input like 5.7 8.6 22 for example. You also have two main methods in your program so one of them should not be denoted with "main" for your program to function properly

Answer (score 0):

`String[] args` comprises the arguments split up by spaces. So, the arguments you want should look like `5 6.3 3`, not `{"5","6.3","3"}`.

Try using `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));` to get a sense for what args actually looks like.